# WFS/NFS Shares lagging then crashing client machines

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, synology, mitel

We're running a Windows domain (2008 R2 on 2 DC's) with a Synology Rackstation hooked up with all our shares on. We have about ~100 workstations and 30 phones hooked up to the domain (the phones have just been merged with our main network from separate).

Everyone is wired in, their connection ends up going through one of our 6 ProCurve switches, 2 of them are PoE switches which are to power the phones but some computers are going through these as well.

We have all our shares under a namespace in DFS management *\\domain.net\Data\Shares* which references *\\NAS-MACHINE\Shares*

Whether or not this is a coincidence I don't know but it's all been working fine up until we added our Mitel phones to our primary network.

I'm seeing more and more issues where people open files from their network shares and either their application (Word/Excel) or their explorer just hangs and subsequently crashes. It doesn't happen to everyone at once, just a few people at different points in the day.

All our DHCP is handled by our DHCP Server (including the phones now which use a custom DHCP option).

Is there a way to diagnose this issue, monitoring traffic through the network?

I feel like it could be one of the following:

- The Phones are causing some kind of problem with the network
- There's something wrong with the DFS Management
- (Very Broad) There's a hardware fault within the network (NAS/Switch)

It's proving difficult to diagnose the issue. It's intermittent and hard to replicate.

We're using a 3300 Mitel Controller with a set of Mitel phones.

Comment: You could start with a packet capture on the system trying to access the share. If you are sure it is the phones, you could isolate them onto their own VLAN to prevent whatever interference you think is causing it.

Comment: What do you mean NFS / WFS?   It seems you are confused and are actually describing samba / CIFS.

Comment: I believe it's CIFS.

Comment: WFS on the Synology was Windows File Sharing just for reference.